# TTCatalog (Three20) wont run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

I'm trying to run the Three20 sample app TTCatalog.
Its compile without errors, but I cant install it in my iPHone or Simulator, it just wont run.
I try using Cmd + R, but nothing. Then I go to product to make it run from there, but the Run word is not able to use it.
I suppose that I set something in te project to make it works, but I dont know what it is.

I have XCode 4.1 on OS X Lion. And I download the project from GitHub (https://github.com/facebook/three20) in a zip file.

Any help will be very appreciate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the target is the test application and not the library itself, if you have the library selected then you can build but the run will be disabled.

Comment: Double check the Scheme drop down in the top left hand corner of the Xcode window.

Answer (score 1):

Try menu
product-->manage schemes-->add 
and select current sample project, TTCatalog

Run again.

Like Simon Lee said, it's a target problem things, just because Three20 didn't add the sample's target default, maybe for a clean library config.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean & Build. set the target to "TTCatalog"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the schemes TTCatalog is selected. It should run then....